# Looking for more efficient Normal Map generation using System.Drawing

Tags: bitmap, textures

I'm currently working on a tool that automatically generates normal maps for a user if they don't have their own to use. This primarily going based on the diffuse texture.

I was able to find a solution for this from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652797/whats-the-logic-behind-creating-a-normal-map-from-a-texture), and while it works as intended, the way its written is not the most efficient.

I've looked into Color Matrix, and Bitmap LockBits but don't quite understand how I would translate this logic 1:1 with those solutions for improving performance. Pixel math unfortunately isn't my strongest skillset here.

As far as I'm aware this current solution uses the Sobel algorithm to generate the normals.

```
        public static Bitmap Calculate(string file) {
            using (Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(file)) {
                int w = image.Width - 1;
                int h = image.Height - 1;
                float sample_l;
                float sample_r;
                float sample_u;
                float sample_d;
                float x_vector;
                float y_vector;
                Bitmap normal = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
                for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                        if (x > 0) {
                            sample_l = image.GetPixel(x - 1, y).GetBrightness();
                        } else {
                            sample_l = image.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                        }
                        if (x < w) {
                            sample_r = image.GetPixel(x + 1, y).GetBrightness();
                        } else {
                            sample_r = image.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                        }
                        if (y > 1) {
                            sample_u = image.GetPixel(x, y - 1).GetBrightness();
                        } else {
                            sample_u = image.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                        }
                        if (y < h) {
                            sample_d = image.GetPixel(x, y + 1).GetBrightness();
                        } else {
                            sample_d = image.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                        }
                        x_vector = (((sample_l - sample_r) + 1) * .5f) * 255;
                        y_vector = (((sample_u - sample_d) + 1) * .5f) * 255;
                        Color col = Color.FromArgb(255, (int)x_vector, (int)y_vector, 255);
                        normal.SetPixel(x, y, col);
                    }
                }
                return normal;
            }
        }
```

I'm mostly looking to find a version of this algorithm that's been written with either Color Matrix or Bitmap LockBits.

The algorithm works as intended, but needs to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately ended up finding [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-Bitmaps-Faster-in-Csharp-3) class which allowed me to keep the code mostly unchanged, while still being able to have the code run faster.

```
public static Bitmap Calculate(string file) {
  using (Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(file)) {
    int w = image.Width - 1;
    int h = image.Height - 1;
    float sample_l;
    float sample_r;
    float sample_u;
    float sample_d;
    float x_vector;
    float y_vector;
    Bitmap normal = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
    LockBitmap source = new LockBitmap(image);
    LockBitmap destination = new LockBitmap(normal);
    source.LockBits();
    destination.LockBits();

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        if (x > 0) {
          sample_l = source.GetPixel(x - 1, y).GetBrightness();
        } else {
          sample_l = source.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
        }
        if (x < w) {
          sample_r = source.GetPixel(x + 1, y).GetBrightness();
        } else {
          sample_r = source.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
        }
        if (y > 1) {
          sample_u = source.GetPixel(x, y - 1).GetBrightness();
        } else {
          sample_u = source.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
        }
        if (y < h) {
          sample_d = source.GetPixel(x, y + 1).GetBrightness();
        } else {
          sample_d = source.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
        }

        x_vector = (((sample_l - sample_r) + 1) * .5f) * 255;
        y_vector = (((sample_u - sample_d) + 1) * .5f) * 255;
        Color col = Color.FromArgb(255, (int)x_vector, (int)y_vector, 255);
        destination.SetPixel(x, y, col);
      }
    }
    destination.UnlockBits();
    source.UnlockBits();
    return normal;
  }
}
```